# Why is my question is closed and do I get views?

Tags: support, closed-questions, views

I have a question about my MathOverflow post: [the minimum amount of x, x(x(125x + 300) + 240) + 64 is zero, what is 5 times of x?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/381796/the-minimum-amount-of-x-xx125x-300-240-64-is-zero-what-is-5-times-of)

Why is my question is closed and do I get views?

Comment: It is good that you’re so interested in math at a young age! This site is for a bit more advanced mathematics; for questions that aren’t about research mathematics but may still be at the Olympiad level, please check out math stackexchange. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the [tour](https://mathoverflow.net/tour)?

> MathOverflow is a question and answer site for **professional mathematicians**.

Your question does not qualify for this; hence it's downvoted and closed. For more details, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

After a question is closed, it can still be viewed.  So the view count can still go up.  You can still edit the question, if you think you can make it into an acceptable question.  Then (with enough votes) the question can be re-opened.

So "closed" is not the same as "gone and forgotten".

Comment: Just to note that the question has been deleted; the OP got frustrated and overwrote the question with "junk text", probably not realizing that he could delete it himself (or perhaps new users are unable to?)

Comment: From the form of the question on main, it looks like the sort of thing done in assignment software that randomizes coefficients and then marks a numerical answer. My suspicion is strengthened by the fact the OP knew that the answer given (a single number) was correct. One could view this meta question as a way of checking if the Q on main is still visible. I hate to be so cynical, but I've done a bit of tracking down of undergrad student cheating lately, for some reason... So I feel the answer on main was supremely unhelpful.